# Getting an image string using base64

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I trying to get base64 string (using'@ionic-native/base64') of an image file uri from ('@ionic-native/image-picker'), but after running this code image seems to be broken. Any suggestions?

My html:

```
<img [src]="base64ImageChosen" *ngIf="base64ImageChosen"/>
```

Picker options:

```
    this.pickerOptions = {
        maximumImagesCount: 1,
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        quality: 100,
        outputType: 0
    };
```

My code:

```
chooseImage() {
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(this.pickerOptions).then((results) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            let filePath: string = results[i];

            this.base64.encodeFile(filePath)
            .then((base64File: string) => {
                this.base64ImageChosen = base64File
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .then((res) =>
                this.myForm.patchValue({ imageChosen: this.base64ImageChosen })
            )
        }
    }, (err) => { });
}
```

Comment: You are fetching the images from the server?

Comment: Images are on the phone, I'm using image-picker plugin to get uri of the image file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the images, you need to use `window.URL.createObjectURL()` which will create a string representing your image object.

```
let image = new Image()
image.src = filePath;
base64ImageChosen = URL.createObjectURL(image);
```

From your code, it seems that you want to display all the images inside a folder. I assume that you are looping inside your html template using `ngFor`.

Comment: Will this code convert base64ImageChosen to base64?

Comment: Yes, it will convert the image. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: Can't wait to try your approach. I'm wondering why my code does not work

Comment: What is `this.base64`? Because there is not any method in vanilla js as `encodeFile()`

Comment: I'm using ionic plugin, base64 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/, that lets me get b64 string from a file uri.

Comment: @viiskis, if my answer helps in anyway do no forget to accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: Will do testing as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

`this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then( (res)=>{
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let base64 =`data:image/jpeg;base64,`+res[i];
        this.images.push(base64);
    }
    })`